# Rails - Remove Event information from Index page post-date (after it has happened)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an events site and on the Index page it shows all events ( represented by an image, title and date). I want to know what code I need to write to remove events from the index page once they've taken place. Do I write a validation method? Is it a model/controller method?

Here's my current Events model and controller code -

Event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :category
belongs_to :user
has_many :bookings
has_many :comments


has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


validates :title, :description, :location, :date, :time, :number_of_spaces, :price_pennies, :category_id, presence: true
validates :title, length: { minimum: 4 }
validates :description, length: { maximum: 250, too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }


monetize :price_pennies
# required for money-rails gem to function

end
```

events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy,]
# the before_actions will take care of finding the correct event for us
# this ties in with the private method below
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
# this ensures only users who are signed in can alter an event

def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @events = Event.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @events = Event.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    # The above code = If there's no category found then all the events are listed
    # If there is then it will show the EVENTS under each category only
end
```

In the controller I have events set up via descending order.I need to write code that will remove an event from the index page once it's happened. I also have a user profile page which shows all the users events that they've created so this will act as an archive of all their events. Its only the index page where they need to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a datetime field named :time. Make sure that when you create an event you set the :time attribute to when the event is going to happen.

Once you have that you can add a scope on the events model.

```
# You can call the scope whatever.
# :happened is the boolean field on the events table.
scope :not_yet_done, -> { where('time >= ?', Time.current) }
```

In your index action:

```
def index
  if params[:category].blank?
    @events = Event.not_yet_done.order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
    @events = Event.not_yet_done.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

Comment: So, I need to do a migration, like - add_happened_to_events happened:boolean and then do the above?

Comment: Yup. Might want to add default: false to that as well to avoid nil values.

Comment: Should I add null: false also to the migration?

Comment: Okay, I've done the migration and updated the code as advised above but the events with a date that's already passed are still showing.

Comment: The :happened attribute for each event needs to be updated to true. This can be done manually or with a background process, but that might be adding another layer of complexity.

If you are checking the events are based on date, a mix of my answer and tGeek's would be your best bet.

Comment: So, the default needs to be reverted to true - not false? So, I need to rollback the previous migration and change it accordingly?

Comment: I've updated as above now none of the events are showing on the index page - even though some (most) are dated after today. Should the scope focus on the date rather than the time? I have both a time and date attribute.

Comment: I've amended the answer accordingly to focus on the :date attribute - this now works as required. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass an extra argument there in that same method and achieve it. It will check if that event with the category id with the date or time inserted (which is greater than the present date or time).

```
def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @events = Event.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @events = Event.where(category_id: @category_id, time:  ">= Time.now.zone").order("created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi, this code gives me a syntax error? It focuses on the =>?

Comment: Fixed it but I'm afraid the above code doesn't do what I need.

Comment: Updated it. Okay ! So, I guess you need another migration like in the other answer.